# How to execute a data factory pipeline with different set of parameters using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a requirement to run the pipeline multiple times with different set of parameters? Can you please help how to iterate the execution for multiple set of parameters?

Below code isn't working:

```
$fileNames =  '"prepTable" = "test_1_ddl"', '"prepTable" = "test_2_ddl"'

$parameters = $fileNames | ForEach-Object {
Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $(rg_nm) -DataFactoryName $(adf_nm) -PipelineName pl_common_Table_Creation_updated -Parameter $parameters }
```

Comment: Isn't working? What's happening? Can you call the pipeline once? Break down the problem to smaller pieces, and actually explain what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nick.McDermaid
Getting below error:

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Parameter'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: You are using `$parameters` as variable that collects the result of the commands inside the orEach-Object loop. That same $parameters variable therefore is null **inside** the loop (`-Parameter $parameters`). The `-Parameter` needs a Hashtable, see [Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/invoke-azdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azps-6.0.0#parameters)

Comment: I am inexperienced in powershell, how can I pass $parameters as Hastable?

I want to run the pipeline twice for below parameters:
'"prepTable" = "test_1_ddl"', '"prepTable" = "test_2_ddl"'

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of Hashtables in PowerShell like this:

```
$prepTables =  @{'prepTable' = 'test_1_ddl'}, @{'prepTable' = 'test_2_ddl'}
```

Then you can use it in a loop like:

```
$prepTables =  @{'prepTable' = 'test_1_ddl'}, @{'prepTable' = 'test_2_ddl'}
$result = $prepTables | ForEach-Object {
    # the $_ Automatic variable represents a single item (hashtable) from the aray
    Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $rg_nm -DataFactoryName $adf_nm -PipelineName 'pl_common_Table_Creation_updated' -Parameter $_
}
```

Personally, I hate those long code lines, so try using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

```
$prepTables =  @{'prepTable' = 'test_1_ddl'}, @{'prepTable' = 'test_2_ddl'}
$result = $prepTables | ForEach-Object {
    $splatParams = @{
        ResourceGroupName = $rg_nm
        DataFactoryName   = $adf_nm
        PipelineName      = 'pl_common_Table_Creation_updated'
        Parameter         = $_   # the $_ Automatic variable represents a single item (hashtable) from the aray
    }
    
    Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline @splatParams
}
```

<sup>P.S. I'm assuming here that your `$(rg_nm)` and `$(adf_nm)` are just placeholders for the real ResourceGroupName and DataFactoryName.
The code above uses variables for those.</sup>